# Fill Two Nicematrices with Different Background Colours Using Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nicematrix

I want to fill these two(2) matrices with two different background colours.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx,animate}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{nicematrix, booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[shrink = 39]
        \frametitle{~}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            remember picture,
            overlay,
            expl/.style={draw=orange,fill=orange!30,rounded corners,text width=9cm},
            arrow/.style={red!80!black,ultra thick,->,>=latex}
            ]
        
            \node[expl]
            (rhootext)
            at (5.5,-3.0cm)
            {\[
                \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
                    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col = 12]
                    x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &     &     &     &     &     &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_1} \\
                    & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &     &     &     &     &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_2} \\
                    &     & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 &     &     &     &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_3} \\
                    &     &     & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &     &     &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_4} \\
                    &     &     &     & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &     &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_5} \\
                    &     &     &     &     & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_6} \\
                    &     &     &     &     &     & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 &        &  & \mathbf{B_7} \\
                    &     &     &     &     &     &     & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10} &  & \mathbf{B_8}
                \end{pNiceMatrix}
                \]};
        
            \node[expl]
            (rhotext)
            at (14.5,-8.8cm)
            {\[
                \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
                \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col = 11]
                    x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &     &     &     &     &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_1} \\
                    & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &     &     &     &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_2} \\
                    &     &     & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &     &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_3} \\
                    &     &     &     & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_4} \\
                    &     &     &     &     &     & x_7 & x_8 & x_9  &        &  \mathbf{B_5} \\
                    &     &     &     &     &     &     & x_8 & x_9  & x_{10} &  \mathbf{B_6} \\
                \end{pNiceMatrix}
                \]};
        
            \draw[arrow]
            (rhootext.east) to[out=0,in=0]([yshift=0.5ex]{rhotext});
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: The two matrices here]

Comment: Either define a `expl2` style where you specify `fill=blue!30` for example, or add a different color in the second node definition: `\node[expl,fill=blue!30]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define in nodes style its colors as options, for example, if the node style name is `box`:

```
   box/.style = {draw=#1, rounded corners, fill=#1!30},
```

and than use as

```
\node[box=cyan] (n1) {...};
```

Considering aforementioned and after introducing new command for shorter writing `\mathbf{B_1}` as `\B_1`, the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,    % <---
                bending,        % <---
                positioning}    % <---
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and -6mm,   % <---
   box/.style = {draw=#1, rounded corners, fill=#1!30}, % <---
   arr/.style = {draw=red!80!black, ultra thick,
                 -{Latex[width=1pt 3,flex]} }           % <---
                    ]
\newcommand\B{\mathbf{B}}   % <---
\node[box=cyan] (n1)        % <---
    {$
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col=11]
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &     &     &     &     &     &     &           & \B_1   \\
    & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &     &     &     &     &     &           & \B_2   \\
    &     & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 &     &     &     &     &           & \B_3   \\
    &     &     & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &     &     &     &           & \B_4   \\
    &     &     &     & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &     &     &           & \B_5   \\
    &     &     &     &     & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 &     &           & \B_6   \\
    &     &     &     &     &     & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 &           & \B_7   \\
    &     &     &     &     &     &     & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10}    & \B_8   
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    $};
\node[box=orange, below right=of n1] (n2)   % <---
    {$
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col=11]
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &     &     &     &     &     &     &           & \B_1   \\
    & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &     &     &     &     &     &           & \B_2   \\
    &     &     & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &     &     &     &           & \B_3   \\
    &     &     &     & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &     &     &           & \B_4   \\
    &     &     &     &     &     & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 &           & \B_5   \\
    &     &     &     &     &     &     & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10}    & \B_6
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    $};
\path[arr]  (n1.east) to[out=0,in=0, looseness=2]    (n2.center);   % <---
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, in MWE is introduced some off-topic changes, which to my opinion make image of matric nicer and code a wee bit shorter and consistent. All changes in comparison to your MWE are marked in code by `% <---`.

Definition for `B` is inserted into `tikzpicture, so it is limited to this image only. However, you can move this definition into document preamble and then use anywhere in document.

[image]

**Addendum:**
It is not clear to me, what is purpose of the arrow between nodes. So I now guess you might like it as drawn in the following picture:

[image]

MWE for above image is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,    
                bending,        
                positioning}    
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and -6mm,   
   box/.style = {draw=#1, rounded corners, thick, fill=#1!15},       % <---
   arr/.style = {draw=red!80!black,line width=2mm, shorten >=-0.5ex, % <---
                 -{Stealth[width=0pt 3,inset=0pt 1, flex]} }         % <---
                    ]
\newcommand\B{\mathbf{B}}   
\node[box=cyan] (n1)    
    {$
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col=11]
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &     &     &     &     &     &     &           & \B_1   \\
    & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &     &     &     &     &     &           & \B_2   \\
    &     & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 &     &     &     &     &           & \B_3   \\
    &     &     & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &     &     &     &           & \B_4   \\
    &     &     &     & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &     &     &           & \B_5   \\
    &     &     &     &     & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 &     &           & \B_6   \\
    &     &     &     &     &     & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 &           & \B_7   \\
    &     &     &     &     &     &     & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10}    & \B_8   
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    $};
\node[box=orange, below right=of n1] (n2)   
    {$
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col=11]
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &     &     &     &     &     &     &           & \B_1   \\
    & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &     &     &     &     &     &           & \B_2   \\
    &     &     & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &     &     &     &           & \B_3   \\
    &     &     &     & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &     &     &           & \B_4   \\
    &     &     &     &     &     & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 &           & \B_5   \\
    &     &     &     &     &     &     & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10}    & \B_6
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    $};
\scoped[opacity=0.3,transparency group]                     % <---
\path[arr]  (n1.east)   to[bend left=45]    (n2.center);    % <---
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All changes in comparison to above MWE are marked in code by % <---

Answer (score 4):

Please clean up your preamble and don't load packages multiple times (`graphicx`, `animate` and `booktabs` are not used in this example, `booktabs` and `nicematrix` are both loaded twice).

Also, you probably don't need the options `remember picture` and `overlay` in this case.

As for your question: Just override the `fill` and `draw` options for one of the nodes to set another color:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        expl/.style={draw=orange,fill=orange!30,rounded corners,text width=9cm},
        arrow/.style={red!80!black,ultra thick,->,>=latex}
    ]
    
        \node[expl, draw=cyan, fill=cyan!30]  % <- add options here (or at the other node)
        (rhootext)
        at (5.5,-3.0cm)
        {\[
            \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
                \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col = 12]
                x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &     &     &     &     &     &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_1} \\
                & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &     &     &     &     &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_2} \\
                &     & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 &     &     &     &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_3} \\
                &     &     & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &     &     &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_4} \\
                &     &     &     & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &     &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_5} \\
                &     &     &     &     & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 &     &        &  & \mathbf{B_6} \\
                &     &     &     &     &     & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 &        &  & \mathbf{B_7} \\
                &     &     &     &     &     &     & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10} &  & \mathbf{B_8}
            \end{pNiceMatrix}
            \]};
    
        \node[expl]
        (rhotext)
        at (14.5,-8.8cm)
        {\[
            \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
            \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col = 11]
                x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &     &     &     &     &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_1} \\
                & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &     &     &     &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_2} \\
                &     &     & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &     &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_3} \\
                &     &     &     & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_4} \\
                &     &     &     &     &     & x_7 & x_8 & x_9  &        &  \mathbf{B_5} \\
                &     &     &     &     &     &     & x_8 & x_9  & x_{10} &  \mathbf{B_6} \\
            \end{pNiceMatrix}
            \]};
    
        \draw[arrow]
        (rhootext.east) to[out=0,in=0]([yshift=0.5ex]{rhotext});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]